# Запуск скрипта JS сразу после загрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, html

Есть большая форма на странице, внутри которой помимо прочего есть `select` и 2 `span`.

При выборе одной из опций `select`'a `span`'ы заполняются Фамилией и Именем руководителя. Все это работает при смене `option`, но не работает сразу при загрузке страницы.

А нужно, чтобы при загрузке страницы при выбранном по умолчанию варианте **А** оба `span` сразу были заполнены - "Иванов Иван", это нужно для дальнейшей отправки формы, если пользователь не будет менять варианты в `select`.

Остальные скрипты написаны на чистом JS. По причине того, что скриптов много, использовать **window.onload** не могу.
Как мне правильно запустить этот скрипт, чтобы это работало сразу после загрузки страницы?

```js
    var club = document.getElementById('clubName');

    function fillcoach() {

    if (club.value == 'А') {
        document.getElementById('coach_family').textContent = 'Иванов';
        document.getElementById('coach_name').textContent = 'Иван';
    }  else if (club.value == 'Б') {
    document.getElementById('coach_family').textContent = 'Петров';
        document.getElementById('coach_name').textContent = 'Петр';
  }

    }
```

```css
.coach {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 100px;
  font-size:16px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<select class="select" id="clubName" onload="fillcoach()" onchange="fillcoach()">
  <option value="А">А</option>
  <option value="Б">Б</option>
</select>

<span class ="coach" id="coach_family" value=""></span>

<span class ="coach" id="coach_name" value=""></span>
```

Comment: Если не хочешь использовать событие `load` на `window`... Можешь просто поместить это скрипт самым последним на странице. Для справки - на событие можно навешивать несколько обработчиков используя метод `addEventListener()`. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: Пробовал последним, он все равно не срабатывает сразу при загрузке, видимо вызов неверно делаю. Про addEventListener() можно поподробнее, а то я только осваиваю JS...

Comment: Так я же тебе ссылку дал на документацию... Вот еще более подробнее. https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onload` не работает для элемента `select`, т.к. он ничего не загружает.
Чтобы решить проблему, как писали в комментарии, нужно скрипт поместить вниз страницы, чтобы на момент выполнения скрипта DOM уже существовал, и после объявления функции `fillcoach()` сразу ее вызывать.

```js
var club = document.getElementById('clubName');

function fillcoach() {

  if (club.value == 'А') {
    document.getElementById('coach_family').textContent = 'Иванов';
    document.getElementById('coach_name').textContent = 'Иван';
  } else if (club.value == 'Б') {
    document.getElementById('coach_family').textContent = 'Петров';
    document.getElementById('coach_name').textContent = 'Петр';
  }

};

fillcoach()
```

```css
.coach {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<select class="select" id="clubName" onchange="fillcoach()">
  <option value="А">А</option>
  <option value="Б">Б</option>
</select>

<span class="coach" id="coach_family" value=""></span>

<span class="coach" id="coach_name" value=""></span>
```